# LoadRunner suggested approach to monitoring cloud based JBoss infrastructure

Tags: jboss, cloud, monitoring, loadrunner, rhq

My Project has a technical platform consisting of a cloud-based set up with JBoss nodes running on Linux VMs and databases connected to these further below.
Obviously I can configure each JBoss instance to accept Remote monitoring via JMX and use VisualVM to monitor them. But as the number of JBoss (combined app server and web app server) increases the monitoring gets out-of-hand as there is a lot of nodes to monitor. I have been thinking about using our JBoss Operations Networking (JON) and maybe monitor on this abstraction level, but is there a way to configure LoadRunner to monitor i.e. through JON?

General question: 
Does anybody have experience in monitoring a could based JBoss infrastructure through LoadRunner or do you monitor through  i.e. JON instead when running the LoadTest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All Monitoring in SiteScope

- Base operating system Monitors through SiteScope
- JMX Monitoring in SiteScope
- (Alternate route) SNMP Agents for JBOSS and your OS, through SiteScope

When you go to run the test, connect to your SiteScope instance from your LR/Performance Center controller and pull in the SiteScope Stats.   As an alternative to SiteScope Business Availability Center can also be used.